# Linq Orderby 'string contains' not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a strange issue trying to order a list based on whether or not it contains a particular string value. Within a view, I have a list on my viewmodel for which I would like to display those objects which are not "snoozed" first and then ordered by whether or not their title contains the word "order". So my code is as follows:

```
var sortedFaults = accountFaultContainer.Faults.Values.OrderBy(f => f.IsSnoozed).ThenByDescending(f => f.Title.ToLower().Contains("order"));
```

I then loop through this list and add the 'faults' to my table using a foreach loop...

```
foreach (Fault fault in sortedFaults)
```

This works in some cases but not in others. I've been trying to single out those that do not behave as expected but there is no clear difference. For example, in once case, a title of "Full failing sync" was ordered both before and after "Failing order syncs". But it is not the case that this always misbehaves; in some tables the ordering is working.

Has anybody come across a similar issue before? Or is there something blatantly obvious I'm missing? I'm scratching my head here!

Answer (score 0):

You order by IsSnoozed first, so that takes priority.

```
 .OrderBy(f => f.IsSnoozed)
 .ThenByDescending(f => f.Title.ToLower().Contains("order"));
```

Try it the other way around:

```
 .OrderBy(f => f.Title.ToLower().Contains("order"))
 .ThenByDescending(f => f.IsSnoozed);
```

Comment: Thanks @buffjape but  I need the orderby snoozed to take priority. I'm having this problem even for a list which has no 'snoozed' items. I would expect that using this code, my list would display all the non-snoozed items with those containing "order" at the top followed by all snoozed items with those which contain "order" in the title before those without